# Fitting a classifier with aymmetric loss and a cumulative objective

Tags: machine-learning, classification, optimization, svm, one-class

I'm looking at classification problems of the form:

$$
\max_{w} \sum_{i} y_i  * (2 * sign(w^T x_i + b) - 1)
$$

I have a set of observations $x_i \in \mathbb{R^n}$ with corresponding values $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ where I can either choose to receive the value $y_i$ (by classifying a point as part of class $1$) or not. This is similar to the weighted classification problem, with an asymmetric loss; I incur zero penalty for points tagged to class $0$, but tagging points with positive $y$ values to class $0$ has an "opportunity cost" in the overall maximization problem. So the goal is to tag as many points with $y_i > 0$ as possible to class $1$ without misclassifying too many points with $y_i<0$ to that class.

Are there studied approaches to this class of problems? My two thoughts were (1) using a one-class weighted classification (e.g. fit on the subset of points where $y_i > 0$) or (2) optimizing the objective numerically. But I couldn't convince myself that (1) was quite right and (2) seems like I'm reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Are your $y\in\{0,1\}$ or $y\in\{-1,+1\}$? You write about "tagging" $y_i$ to $0$ (are "tags" the true classes, or your classifications?), but then also about $y_i<0$. Please clarify.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I've updated the question. $y$ are real-valued, however the model output is binary. A toy example would be a multi-stage game where each round you can choose to "play" or "pass." If you choose to play, you win or lose some number of points; if you "pass," you don't gain/lose anything; and your goal is to maximize your score over N rounds.

Comment: This could be perhaps [Learning with rejection](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/pub/rej.pdf)